# How to consolidate multiple values into one value using case when and partition by in SQL?

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition, dense-rank

I have a table that contains 3 distinct names in one field, the respective account those names are associated to, Unique IDs, the total counts for each pair, and a rank column based on the total counts value. Example here:

```
LOGO     |  Account |  ID    |   Count_Per_Logo   |  Rank

Walmart     Acct_A     ABC          3                 1
Walmart     Acct_A     DEF          3                 1
Walmart     Acct_A     GHI          3                 1
Vudu        Acct_A     JKL          1                 2
Bonobos     Acct_A     MNO          1                 2
```

My goal is to 'consolidate' the LOGO field into just one Logo to one Account - so for each of the unique ID's - they should only be associated to 1 logo (instead of the 3 shown above).

## Desired Output

```
LOGO     |  Account |  ID    |   Count_Per_Logo   |  Rank   | Consolidated_LOGO

Walmart     Acct_A     ABC          3                 1       Walmart     
Walmart     Acct_A     DEF          3                 1       Walmart     
Walmart     Acct_A     GHI          3                 1       Walmart     
Vudu        Acct_A     JKL          1                 2       Walmart     
Bonobos     Acct_A     MNO          1                 2       Walmart
```

Right now I am using a count with partition by to get the rank - but I'm unsure how to create a new field that has the 'desired logo' based on the rank values - would a lag function be necessary for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated

### Current logic

```
SELECT LOGO, ACCOUNT, ID FROM
(SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY LOGO_NAME_CNT DESC) AS LOGO_RANK
FROM
(SELECT *, count(ACCOUNT) over (partition by LOGO) AS LOGO_NAME_CNT FROM "TABLE1" WHERE ACCOUNT = 'Acct_A')
)
WHERE LOGO_RANK = 1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Snowflake

Comment: What if the ranks are tied due to equal counts?

Comment: @PhilCoulson That is why I wanted to use dense_rank() -- Ideally, for all accounts that are associated to a LOGO that is > 1 in Rank - would take the Rank 1 LOGO -- I'm just trying to figure out if I need to use a union or self-join approach to get that logic in the new field created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like your base SQL is:

```
SELECT
    a.*
    ,dense_rank() over (partition by account order by count_per_logo desc) as rank
FROM (
    SELECT 
        logo
        ,account
        ,id
        ,count(logo) over (partition by account, logo) as count_per_logo
    FROM VALUES 
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'abc'),   
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'def'), 
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'ghi'),
        ('vudu', 'acct_a', 'jkl'),
        ('bonobos', 'acct_a', 'mno')
        v(logo, account, id)
) AS a
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 5;
```

then all you need to add is a [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) like:

```
SELECT
    a.*
    ,dense_rank() over (partition by account order by count_per_logo desc) as rank
    ,first_value(logo) over (partition by account order by count_per_logo desc) as Consolidated_LOGO
FROM (
    SELECT 
        logo
        ,account
        ,id
        ,count(logo) over (partition by account, logo) as count_per_logo
    FROM VALUES 
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'abc'),   
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'def'), 
        ('walmart', 'acct_a', 'ghi'),
        ('vudu', 'acct_a', 'jkl'),
        ('bonobos', 'acct_a', 'mno')
        v(logo, account, id)
) AS a
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 5;
```

which gives::

| LOGO | ACCOUNT | ID | COUNT_PER_LOGO | RANK | CONSOLIDATED_LOGO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| walmart | acct_a | abc | 3 | 1 | walmart |
| walmart | acct_a | def | 3 | 1 | walmart |
| walmart | acct_a | ghi | 3 | 1 | walmart |
| vudu | acct_a | jkl | 1 | 2 | walmart |
| bonobos | acct_a | mno | 1 | 2 | walmart |

Answer (score 1):

Simeon's answer should work as long as you don't have ties. Actually, if you don't care for ties, it gets even simpler

```
select logo,
       account,
       id,
       mode(logo) over (partition by account) as consolidated_logo
from your_table;
```

If you want the result set to replicate for each instance of logo that ties on count, consider below

```
with cte as

(select logo, account 
 from your_table 
 group by logo, account
 qualify max(count(*)) over (partition by account)=count(*))


select a.*, b.logo as consolidated_logo
from your_table a
join cte b on a.account=b.account
order by b.logo;
```